# FindMinimum diverges

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I just enocountered following issue, `FindMinimjum` explicitly diverges — final result is WORSE than initial supplied conditions.

> During evaluation of In[37]:= FindMinimum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 500 iterations.
>
> `{{21552.2, 
>   {k1 -> 7.60098, k2 -> -13.9876, k3 -> 8.31783, 
>    k4 -> 16.4603, k5 -> 11.6401, k6 -> 6.50849}}}`

Whereas value at arbitrary initial conditions is:

```
Re[finaleq3] /. 
  {d -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.55, k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1, k3 -> 1, k4 -> 1, k5 -> 1, k6 -> 1}
```

> `2590.2`

Here's a minimum working part of my script:

```
dmat[d_] := {{1, -2 d, d*d}, {0, 1, -d}, {0, 0, 1}};
c0[k_, l_] := Cos[Sqrt[k]*l];
s0[k_, l_] := 1/Sqrt[k]*Sin[Sqrt[k]*l];
cp[k_, l_] := -Sqrt[k]*Sin[Sqrt[k]*l];
sp[k_, l_] := Cos[Sqrt[k]*l];
frmat[k_,l_] := 
  {{c0[k, l]*c0[k, l], -2*s0[k, l]*c0[k, l], s0[k, l]*s0[k, l]}, 
   {-c0[k, l]*cp[k, l], s0[k, l]*cp[k, l] + sp[k, l]*c0[k, l], -s0[k, l]*sp[k, l]}, 
   {cp[k, l]*cp[k, l], -2*cp[k, l]*sp[k, l], sp[k, l]*sp[k, l]}}
finalmatx = 
  dmat[d1] . frmat[k6, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[k5, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[k4, 0.1] . 
  dmat[d] . frmat[k3, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[k2, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[k1, 0.1] . 
  dmat[d1];
finalmaty = 
  dmat[d1] . frmat[-k6, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[-k5, 0.1] . dmat[d] . 
  frmat[-k4, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[-k3, 0.1] . dmat[d] . frmat[-k2, 0.1] .  
  dmat[d] . frmat[-k1, 0.1] . dmat[d1];

tx03 = {31.896, -11.249, 3.999};
txu3 = {3.915, -1.868, 1.147};
ty03 = {20.115, 3.350, 0.608};
tyu3 = {1.193, 0.607, 1.147};
finaleqx3 = (txu3 - finalmatx.tx03).(txu3 - finalmatx.tx03);
finaleqy3 = (tyu3 - finalmaty.ty03).(tyu3 - finalmaty.ty03);
finaleq3 = finaleqx3 + finaleqy3;
resultlist3 = {};

AppendTo[
  resultlist3, 
  FindMinimum[
    {Re[finaleq3] /. {d -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.55}, 
     -20 <= k1 <= 20, -20 <= k2 <= 20, -20 <= k3 <= 20, -20 <= k4 <= 20, 
     -20 <= k5 <= 20, -20 <= k6 <= 20}, 
    {{k1, 1}, {k2, 1}, {k3, 1}, {k4, 1}, {k5, 1}, {k6, 1}}]]
```

#### Note 1

Matrices `frmat` are purely linear and equations `finaleqx3, finaleqy3` and `finaleq3` are real, but for some reason Mathematica insists on keeping a vanished imaginary term, which is the reason why I had to use `Re`.

```
finaleq3 /. 
  {d -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.55, k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1, k3 -> 1, k4 -> 1, k5 -> 1, k6 -> 1}
```

> `590.2 + 0. I`

It's easy to check that all imaginary numbers cancel out within `c0`, `s0`, `cp` and `sp` terms used in `frmat` and have no right appearing dragging on to final result.

#### Note 2

I'm making such minimizations for different values of `tx0` and `ty0` (script here is for 3rd set of `tx0/ty0` values), some minimize successfully, some diverge like the case discussed above.

I'd like to find out what's happening and how can I work around this problem. Thanks for any help.

#### Edit

I just found out that increasing `MaxIterations` to 5000 allowed this particular minimization to evaluate successfully. However, `MaxIterations` did not help with a different set of `tx0/ty0`. Besides that, I'm quite perplexed as to why intermediate values in successful optimisation are so much worse than initial ones.

Comment: The `Complex` numbers are introduced by taking `Sqrt` of a negative number.  As with most computer languages, computations with type `Complex` do not automatically revert to type `Real` when the imaginary part happens to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Making

```
obj = finaleq3 /. {d -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.55}  
NMinimize[{obj, -20 <= k1 <= 20, -20 <= k2 <= 20, -20 <= k3 <= 20, -20 <= k4 <= 20, -20 <= k5 <= 20, -20 <= k6 <= 20}, {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6}]

(*{0.0000173175, {k1 -> 16.6323, k2 -> -18.4756, k3 -> 18.8806, k4 -> 19.223, k5 -> -17.8192, k6 -> 18.7899}}*)
```

Appears to work properly.

Comment: Hmm. You are also using NMinimize while I used FindMinimum. I'll look into your solution later today. Thanks for your time.